# getting error while multiplying two numbers in c#

Tags: c#

I am unable to find the service tax of a product. How do I get the service tax of a product? Should I use `decimal` or `double`? while using double its not giving error.

string StrVatPercentage = vatPercentage.Text;

```
decimal totalprice = Convert.ToDecimal(qty) * Convert.ToDecimal(price);
    // totalprice = 497080M // qty = 4 // price= 124,270.00

decimal serviceTaxPrice = totalprice * Convert.ToDecimal(StrVatPercentage)/100;
    // strVtPercentage=12.36M- getting error in this line
```

Comment: Going to need some example values for `ServiceTaxPercentag.Value`, `StrVatPercentage`, `qty`, `price`. Which line is giving an error?

Comment: What error exactly does it say? Or is it not throwing a error and instead getting a math error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the value you have for StrVatPercentage.  You say it is equal to "12.36m-".  This will not convert because it is in the incorrect format.  I run this

```
 decimal totalprice = Convert.ToDecimal("4") * Convert.ToDecimal("124,270.00");
 decimal serviceTaxPrice = totalprice * Convert.ToDecimal("12.36") / 100;
```

And it works just fine.